# (Redux Persist) TypeError: storage.getItem(...).then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm attempting to integrate with redux persist in my React application using Redux Toolkit. I'm getting the following error with my integration though:

```
TypeError: storage.getItem(...).then is not a function
```

Here's what my store looks like:

```
const transientReducer = combineReducers({
  loading: loadingSlice.reducer,
});

const persistentReducer = persistReducer({
  key: "root",
  storage: localStorage,
}, combineReducers({
  test: testSlice.reducer,
})); 

const reducer = combineReducers({
  transient: transientReducer,
  persistent: persistentReducer,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({ 
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
    }
  })
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Here's what my App.tsx setup looks like:

```
<Provider
  store={store}
>
  <PersistGate
    persistor={persistor}
    loading={null}
  >
    <App />
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you are using the global `localStorage` object.  You want to import the settings from the `redux-persist` package instead.

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
```

[docs link](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines)